# ObjectDisposeException when trying to send through a reopened socket

Tags: c#, sockets, objectdisposedexception

1. I'm using `Socket` (`Socket A = new Socket...`) to send/receive.
2. when something bed happens (disconnection), I'm trying to close/dispose old object, and then instancing a new socket (`A = new Socket...`) (same host/port)
3. The `connect()` phase checks out fine, the remote host sees the connection.
4. Upon trying to send the very first byte, I immediately get:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer)

Any Ideas?

```
try
{
   CCMSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.NoDelay, true);
   CCMSocket.Connect(CCMServer, CCMPort);
}
```

Now, when working with the socket, the catch clause catches `SocketException`, and calls the reconnect method:

```
try
{
    //Verify the the socket is actually disconnected
    byte[] Empty = new byte[0];
    CCMSocket.Send(Empty);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    bool connected = false;
    int reconnectCounter = 0;
    do
    {
        reconnectCounter++;
        Disconnect(); //<-- Just CCMSocket.Disconnect(true) in a try/catch
        if (Connect(CCMServer, CCMPort)) // <-- method given above
        {
            connected = true;
            CCMSocket.Send(LoginData); // this fails
        }
    } while (!connected);    
}
```

Comment: Could we get a look at your code to see how you are disposing your objects.

Comment: can you post some code extracts, sounds like you are using the same reference

Comment: Do you use `using` block against `Socket` object anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Have your Connect method create a **new** socket and return that socket to send data.
Something more like:

```
try
{
   CCMSocket = new Socket();
   CCMSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.NoDelay, true);
   CCMSocket.Connect(CCMServer, CCMPort);
   return CCMSocket
}
```

and

```
do
{
    reconnectCounter++;
    Disconnect(); //<-- Just CCMSocket.Disconnect(true) in a try/catch
    var newSocket = Connect(CCMServer, CCMPort); // <-- method given above
    if (newSocket != null) 
    {
        connected = true;
        newSocket.Send(LoginData); // should work
        CCMSocket = newSocket; // To make sure existing references work
    }
} while (!connected);
```

You should also seriously consider the [asynchronous socket pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx) when building server applications.